# how to use dropdown value in mysql query?

Tags: php, jquery, html, mysql, ajax

i am creating a module,in that i had created a link which will display database in the form of table. and i put a select option in the top which will select name of one column present in the database table. once the user clicks on leave type from dropdown and click on the link displaying database it show filtered table containing only specified leave type. right now it is displaying all leave_types.
Help is appreciated.
below is my code and screenshot.

```
<select id="subject34" name="subject" class="span3">
<option   value="na" selected="">Choose One:</option>
<option   value="Vacation Leave">Vacation Leave</option>
<option   value="sick Leave">Sick Leave</option>
<option   value="Child Care Leave">Child Care Leave</option>
</select>




<div id="test7766" style="overflow:scroll; height:200px; width:100%;                                     display:none">
<?php

$query = "
SELECT t1.emp_id
     , t1.leave_from
     , t1.leave_to
     , t1.leave_reason
     , t1.leave_requested_date
     , t1.count_day
     , t2.leave_type
     , t3.emp_name 
  FROM pro_emp_leave_dtl as t1
  LEFT 
  JOIN pro_emp_leave_component as t2 
    ON t1.emp_id = t2.emp_id
  LEFT 
  JOIN pro_emp_mst as t3
    ON t2.emp_id = t3.emp_id
 WHERE t1.employee_orignal_id = '".$_SESSION['ADMIN_GAME_ID']."'
";
$result = mysql_query($query);

echo "<table>"; // start a table tag in the HTML

echo "<tr>";
echo "<td><b>Emp Id</h4></b>";
echo "<td><b>Emp Name</b></td>";
echo "<td><b>Leave Reason</b></td>";
echo "<td><b>Leave Type</b></td>";
echo "<td><b>Leave Date</b></td>";
echo "<td><b>Count Day</b></td>";
echo "<td><b>Leave From</b></td>";
echo "<td><b>Leave To</b></td>";
echo "</tr>";

while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {

   // Write the value of the column FirstName (which is now in the array         $row)
  echo "<tr>";
  echo "<td>" . $row['emp_id'] . "</td>";
  echo "<td>" . $row['emp_name'] . "</td>";
  echo "<td>" . $row['leave_reason'] . "</td>";
  echo "<td>" . $row['leave_type'] . "</td>";
  echo "<td>" . $row['leave_requested_date'] . "</td>";
  echo "<td>" . $row['count_day'] . "</td>";
  echo "<td>" . $row['leave_from'] . "</td>";
  echo "<td>" . $row['leave_to'] . "</td>";
  echo"</tr>";

  }


// Close the database connection
mysql_close();

echo "</table>";
?>
</div>
```

Screenshot:
[screenshot 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dYsuu.png)

[screenshot 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2YkdK.png)

Comment: do use [ajax](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/) on the select box [onchange()](http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_ajax_database.asp) event and let us know if not working

Comment: using javascript i am getting the value of the select option, i just want to know is it possible to use that js val in query.\

Comment: Yes use that value for ajax